# mongodb lookup with collection and dynamic query output

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have some dynamic query for a collection

```
var condition = dynmic_query
db.collection.find(condition)
```

is giving me an output

now what I need whatever I am getting from previous query need to lookup with an another collection.

I am scared if this is not possible yet in mongodb

[https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22497]

I did some google but not getting idea how to achieve this one

I have to execute this query in node.js

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Post your code with detailed explanation....

Comment: the sql join equivalent?

Comment: This looks like a basic lookup scenario.How is this related to SERVER-22497 ? Do your output from find contain the collection name that you would like to use in `from` field in lookup stage ? Please add some data and query to the post.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I have added a simple and easy solution please have a look. +1 for your question!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need the [Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) with the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) pipeline stage with a `$match` pipeline. It's a bit like doing a JOIN from the SQL world. Here's an example:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "warehouses",
           let: { order_item: "$item", order_qty: "$ordered" },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$stock_item",  "$$order_item" ] },
                         { $gte: [ "$instock", "$$order_qty" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              },
              { $project: { stock_item: 0, _id: 0 } }
           ],
           as: "stockdata"
         }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use one query output in second query. But you need to handle this at your code level.

hit one query and kept result in one variable then use that result to search in another query.

Mongodb is not meant for complex fetch. That's the whole reason it gives you high performance.